# Expand box with content

Tags: html, css

Sorry for a weird title but I don't really know how to describe it easily.

First I'll link my JSFiddle on it http://jsfiddle.net/b7YTd/

When I added the "float: left" and "float: right" the rows jumped outside the box and the box doesn't expand as the content gets "larger".

My question is, how do I make the box expand after the content like it should do with content inside it if it doesn't have a set height?

In order to post my JSFiddle I need to add some code so my CSS:

```
#profile_friends {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: -10px;
background: rgb(240,240,240);
border: 2px solid #555;
border-radius: 3px;
width: 100%;
}

.friend_left {
float: left;
width: 250px;
}

.friend_right {
float: right;
width: 250px;
}

.friend img {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
float: left;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 8px;
}

.friend ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin-top: -15px;
margin-left: 35px;
}

#profile_friends h4 {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: rgb(110,110,110);
font-weight: bold;
height: 20px;
}

#profile_friends hr {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly use:

```
#friendlist {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b7YTd/1/

Comment: @JoshC no it wouldn't. If his margins, paddings, or widths are off, in 'overflow:auto' he would know it. In 'overflow:hidden' he would not. Hence, 'overflow:auto' is more semantic and proper, although I admit some are afraid to use it because they get scrollbars. If they are getting scrollbars, then perhaps they are not semantic with the rest of their code, or their math is wrong...

Comment: Got an little additional problem, when I add more than 2 friends it continues on one row instead of making another row below. http://jsfiddle.net/b7YTd/2/

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, but used overflow:hidden; on the parent div.

http://jsfiddle.net/b7YTd/3/

```
#profile_friends {
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: -10px;
background: rgb(240,240,240);
border: 2px solid #555;
border-radius: 3px;
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
```

}